# UniRX, how much of it should I use? for good optimization

Tags: unity

I come from the Front End dev world and I'm taking my baby steps in Unity.

I'm already very familiar with RXJS and glad to see it being re-coded into almost every other big language (there's starting to be quite a few) :

Java: RxJava
JavaScript: RxJS
C#: Rx.NET
C#(Unity): UniRx
Scala: RxScala
Clojure: RxClojure
C++: RxCpp
Lua: RxLua
Ruby: Rx.rb
Python: RxPY
Go: RxGo
Groovy: RxGroovy
JRuby: RxJRuby
Kotlin: RxKotlin
Swift: RxSwift
PHP: RxPHP
Elixir: reaxive
Dart: RxDart

And as I discovered and as you can see, it is available in Unity-flavor.

here's a quick intro :
https://youtu.be/kFoBvjwzbNA

But not every framework or environment or every variable and event is necessarily improved by RX, or is it?

Since I don't quite understand how Unity operates internally (nor do I plan to do that fully, I have a game to make), I'd like to know is it a performance gain or a performance loss, to use UniRX to (for example) store every input my game might need into observables,

and then susbcribe to those observable versions of user Inputs wherever applicable in my C# scripts?,

or does the repeated use of the Update() method to listen to inputs in multiple scripts get interpreted somehow by Unity at compile to automatically optimize the built code and adding my extra RX step would just be a net loss?

What about game state, and, say I'm coding an RTS, unit states?

What about RayCast Hits, should I make those observable?

What UniRX usages are poor practice, and which result in performance gain/optimized code? (especially with my given examples in mind)

The obvious use-case is game UI, obviously, but disregarding that, what could I extend UniRx usages to?

[PS: Since UniRX is a relatively new topic here could someone with 3000+ points create the unirx tag and add it to my question please?]